# Page refresh function if all three select boxes have a chosen value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have 3 select boxes and a submit button. If no value has been selected in any of the select boxes nothing happens when the submit button is clicked. If values have been selected in all 3 of the select boxes then clicking on the submit button refreshes the page with a 2 second delay.

Here's what I have so far that doesn't work:

HTML

```
<select class="select1" name="select1">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="5">Blue</option>
<option value="6">Green</option>
<option value="7">Red</option>
</select>

<select class="select2" name="select2">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="5">big</option>
<option value="6">small</option>
<option value="7">medium</option>
</select>

<select class="select3" name="select3">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="5">1</option>
<option value="6">2</option>
<option value="7">3</option>
</select>


<input type="submit" value="something1" name="something2" onclick="refresh(2000)" class="something3" id="something4">
```

JS

```
if($(".select1" && ".select2" && ".select3")).value !== "0") {
    function refresh (timeoutPeriod){refresh = setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod);}
}
```

But the problem Im having here as well is that refresh would not be defined is the statement is not true(onload etc). I have looking around for a couple of hours and can't really find much, or maybe im not doing something right. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `$(".select1" && ".select2" && ".select3")` – that does not do what you think it does …

Comment: And defining your function within an if-statement also makes little sense; apart from that, you are not calling that function. You should really learn some JS basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a more elegant solution?

HTML:

```
<select class="select1" onchange="handleChange($(this))">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="5">Blue</option>
<option value="6">Green</option>
<option value="7">Red</option>
</select>

<select class="select2" onchange="handleChange($(this))">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="5">big</option>
<option value="6">small</option>
<option value="7">medium</option>
</select>

<select class="select3" onchange="handleChange($(this))">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="5">1</option>
<option value="6">2</option>
<option value="7">3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" onclick="tryRefresh(2000)">
```

JS

```
var selected = 0;
function handleChange($select) {
  $select.val() ? selected++ : selected--;
}

function tryRefresh(delay) {
  if (selected === 3) {
    setTimeout(refresh, delay);
  }
}

function refresh() {
  window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with your current code:

- Incorrect use of jQuery Selectors `$(".select1" && ".select2"`..

  - jQuery Selectors use CSS like selector texts, to collect multiple rules
  - Because it's three different values you're checking, you'd have to check each
     one.
- Scoping and placement of function `refresh()` is ambiguous and uncalled.
- jQuery doesn't have a `.value` property, you'd have to call it via `.val()` for jQuery objects.

---

```
<script>
function refresh() {
    if( $(".select1 option:selected").val() !== "0" && 
        $(".select2 option:selected").val() !== "0" && 
        $(".select3 option:selected").val() !== "0" ) {

        setTimeOut(function(){ 
           window.location.reload();
        }, 2000 );
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need `option:selected` in your selector.  Also, you want `!= "0"`, not `==`, and you should be using `&&`, not `||`.  Geblord wants to reload the page if all 3 items have a selection.

Comment: Oops! thanks =) My answer there would of been the easiest to pass form ever! :D

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked perfectly for me, but I used Code pirates because it's more effective if the class names change within my loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong at a place,

```
if($(".select1" && ".select2" && ".select3")).value !== "0") {
 function refresh (timeoutPeriod) {
  refresh = setTimeout(function() {
   window.location.reload(true);
  },timeoutPeriod);
 }
}
```

This won't work. In computer language, you need to check one condition, then move on to the other.

The condition you are using would work if all the operators were bool such as

```
if((bool1 && bool2 && bool3) {
  /* code executes if all three bools are true!
   */
}
```

So what you need is, this:

```
if($('.select1'.val() != '0' && 
     '.select2'.val() != '0' && 
     '.select3'.val() != 0)) {
 function refresh (timeoutPeriod) {
  refresh = setTimeout(function() { 
    window.location.reload(true);
  }, timeoutPeriod);
 }
}
```

This way, you will first check the select1 then select2 and then the last one, if they all don't have the `0` value. then the function will continue. Otherwise it will stay as it is.

Here is a fiddle for the algorithm: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/tSDKN/2/

I am sorry, I have short time left to pray! So you can get the basic code from fiddle :) I have explained how the select works there.

Good luck brother.